# csc compiler for C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, csc, cl

I am using Visual studio 2015. I think it uses the cl.exe compiler which is inside the Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin folder to compile C++ code. Also, my understanding is that the compiler used to compile C# code is csc.exe. However, I could not find this csc.exe inside my visual studio like cl.exe. I am curious to know how visual studio compiles C# code then. I think Visual Studio uses the csc.exe which comes with .Net, generally installed in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\csc.exe to compile C# code. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I have just [answer another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939232/815938) on this topic. Please check. Visual Studio 2015 uses the default Roslyn compiler, not the one shipped with .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the link. Inmycase, my visual studio 2015 does-not have Roslyn\csc.exe. Basically it does-not have csc.exe installed. So in this case, can we assume it is taking csc.exe from my .Net installation?

Comment: Did you install VS2015 or did someone else install it?  Was the option to install C# unticked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer why Roslyn is not present in your VS 2015 install dir. But you can examine how Visual Studio runs the csc.exe in the output window.

Go to `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run`, and select the build output verbosity. (you can select the most verbose option)

[image]

Then build your program. You can then check the command line used by `MSBuild` in the output window.

Something like, ooh, I am using VS 2017...

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred ... (a bunch of switches omitted)

Comment: Thanks got it, I see in mycase it is taking csc.exe from the following path -- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe